# Can't see other Mac workstation via ethernet but OK over Wi-Fi

Tags: network, wifi, sharing, ethernet

So, I upgraded router to latest DD-WRT firmware.

Now, for some reason, can't see my Mac Desktop from my MacBook if connected to Ethernet. Macbook has DHCP, Mac Desktop has DHCP with manual IP.

I can see the Mac Desktop if I connect via Wi-Fi, but not through ethernet.

I've released / renewed DHCP a few times, rebooted, flushed dscache, power cycled router.

Comment: And if you roll back to the previous version of dd-wrt firmware, is there the same problem? L.A.G.S. will bite you at some point.

Comment: i don't know if I can roll back. What is L.A.G.S?

Comment: L.A.G.S. = Latest And Greatest Syndrome. Can you ping the desktop when connected via ethernet? It sounds like something is blocking mDNS (Bonjour) on the ethernet side.

Comment: Hi, so it seems the problem is in the DD-WRT firmare upgrade. I downgraded to a previous DD-WRT and the issue is gone. It was a matter of lan switching not working.

Answer (score 1):

so it seems the problem is in the DD-WRT firmare upgrade. I downgraded to a previous DD-WRT and the issue is gone. It was a matter of lan switching not working.

Downgrading back to DD-WRT firmware SVN revision 23919 fixed it.